# Execute bash commands that are included in a csv file

Tags: bash, macos

I have a `csv` file with only one column and each row includes a custom bash function, like this:

```
my_func 1 a
my_func 1 b
my_func 1 c
```

where the `my_func` function is included in the `~/.bash_profile`, which I can run normally in the bash shell.
What I want to do is to run each one of the above commands in a bash shell sequentially. Is there an easy way to do so (I want to avoid copy/paste each command in the bash shell)?

Edit: When I try to `bash filename.csv` I get the following error: `line1: my_func: command not found`.

Comment: what is a  custom bash command?

Comment: Where is `my_func` defined...? Another file? Can you run it from the shell? Is it a script or a function?

Comment: It's not a CSV file; it's just a regular text file. (Or at least, it is only vacuously a CSV file, and isn't relevant to the question.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that's the file as you portray it then

```
/bin/bash <yourfile>
```

really doesn't matter what the file name ending is. You could also stick a:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

at the top, give run permission (`chmod u+x yourfile`) and run it as:

```
./yourfile
```

Your CSV file, is in fact, a bash script.

**EDIT**

Following your edit, you can source the `csv` in current bash shell, so you have access to the function:

```
. yourfile
```

I think the second method (adding a shebang and running the file directly) will also work - if not, try putting the function in `.bashrc` rather than the profile. More solutions - source the profile at the top of the CSV, define the function at the top, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I edited a little bit the question.

Comment: @thanasissdr then that function is not defined anywhere. Where did you expect it to come from? please amend the question to show the actual file with the actual command (can you run the function in the shell for example)?

Comment: @thanasissdr np, don't forget to accept (and not just upvote). Thanks.